# Как организовать хранение и быстрый поиск данных?

Tags: delphi, хеширование, хранение-данных, delphi-xe, поисковая-оптимизация

Проблема в следующем... Программа множественными хитрыми вычислениями генерирует массивы `arr: array[0..n] of byte`, где `n <= 255`. `n` может меняться от задачи, но в пределах одной задачи - константа. Массивов может быть до нескольких миллиардов (в худшем случае в пределах типа `Cardinal` думаю, чаще всего конечно меньше)...
Каждый массив это, скажем так, узел графа. И нужно каким-то образом по возможности быстро определить был ли уже такой узел и если да, то получить его индекс, чтобы с ним построить связь. Так как сами массивы, естественно, храниться не будут, т.к. их хранение потребовало бы слишком много памяти.

1. Что можно взять за основу такой конструкции? Как я понимаю нужен список хешей: index, hash. `TDictionary` справится с такой задачей или его не зря советуют не использовать? https://habr.com/post/282902/
2. Может `THashedStringList`, `TBucketList` или есть ещё что-то подходящее? Хотелось бы чтобы эти хеши "умно" складывались в памяти, чтобы потом по ним был достаточно быстрый поиск, типа бинарного.
3. И с Hash-функцей вопрос... Её в этих стандартных структурах можно как-то переопределять или стандартная справится? Она обычно от строки берётся? Можно конечно массив загонять в какую-нибудь hex-строку, но на сколько это целесообразно?

Comment: Давно не писал на делфи, но я бы сделал свою собственную хеш таблицу. Удаление из таблицы - самая сложная операция, и она вам не нужна. Я не знаю, как делфи считает хеш код для массива байт, но если он делает это плохо, можно попробовать скопировать версию хеш кода для byte[] из джава.

Comment: Любое хэширование предполагает коллизии, поэтому оригинальные массивы хранить вам придётся в любом случае. Не в памяти, так на диске.

Comment: Стандартный словарь с его хешем вам не подойдет, поскольку для хранения значения хэша в нем предусмотрен тип `Integer`, а у вас количество массивов в пределе до размерности `Cardinal`. На мой взгляд, хэши тут бесполезны. Лучшим вариантом, как мне кажется, будет поиск по сортированному списку массивов двоичным поиском. Чтобы не держать весь список в памяти, можно делать поиск по файлу, считывая массивы по одному. Но если вам нужно будет добавлять туда новые массивы в процессе, то этот вариант тоже не подойдет.

Comment: а не вариант часть работы в СУБД перенести ?

Comment: @teran, да в общем ничего этому не препятствует... Подробнее эту идею можно? Я пока не понял зачем

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, добавлять в процессе надо будет... Если я логику сверну до Integer, то подойдёт стандартный словарь? Или, как написал выше zed, он коллизии всё равно допускает?

Comment: @Isaev да без  идей. если есть много данных и нужен по ним поиск, то в целом задача для СУБД. вопрос только, как вы вообще собираетесь оперировать 4294967295 массивами длиной по 255 байт? это ж терабайт целый с хвостиком.

Comment: а хотя хранить если не надо, то СУБД не в тему. Но и разместить в памяти такой объем тоже не выйдет. в целом надо все равно временно писать на диск. а СУБД дает эффективный способ упорядоченного/индексированного хранения на диске, хоть пусть и временного.

Comment: @Isaev, как это "логику сверну"? У вас в принципе предполагается вариантов массивов больше, чем в `Integer` помещается. Только если уменьшить количество массивов, причем значительно меньше чем помещается в `Integer`, чтобы можно было положится на алгоритм хэширования и надеяться, что для всех ваших вариантов массивов хэш всегда будет разный.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci в смысле там можно будет исключить симметрии относительно всех осей, зеркальные отображения и прочее. В результате количество в integer должно влезть... На счёт "значительно меньше", мне говорили конечно, что хеш функция там какая-то простенькая, типа црц32, которая конечно должна допускать коллизии, но с другой стороны какой был смысл добавлять в яп структуру, которая настолько не надёжна? С количеством вариантов вероятность появления коллизии просто увеличивается, но это же значит, что она возможна и для 10 записей! Зависит только от данных. Зачем тогда она нужна?